# Resolve an Interface using Unity 2.1

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a basic class that is trying to resolve an interface using Unity.

```
            IUnityContainer containter = new UnityContainer();

            containter.RegisterType<IRepositoryFactory>();

            IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory = containter.Resolve<IRepositoryFactory>();
```

My config file is as follows:

```
<unity>
    <containers>
        <container>
            <types>
                <type   name="IRepositoryFactory"
                        type="QuinntyneBrown.Interfaces.IRepositoryFactory"
                        mapTo="QuinntyneBrown.Photography.Factories.RepositoryFactory" />
            </types>
        </container>
    </containers>
</unity>
```

I'm getting the following error:

Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "QuinntyneBrown.Interfaces.IRepositoryFactory", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.

### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, QuinntyneBrown.Interfaces.IRepositoryFactory, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving QuinntyneBrown.Interfaces.IRepositoryFactory,(none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
containter.RegisterType<IRepositoryFactory>();
```

This doesn't make any binding. Load bindings from your config file instead:

```
containter.LoadConfiguration();
```